# How can I display TimeSpan values as the X-axis on a chart in C# 2008?

Tags: c#, charts, timespan

I have values in the form of a timespan (Day. HH:mm:ss is the format, although they don't contain the day for values under 24 hours) which I would like to display as the X-axis of a chart, yet I only have DateTime as the XValueType, and it won't accept a timestamp value. Is there any way to get round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert `TimeSpan` to `DateTime` you need to have and add a **base date** the `TimeSpans` are referring to.

Then you can write:

```
DateTime dt = baseDate.Add(yourTimeSpan);
```

You will want to set `AxisX.LabelStyle.Format` and `AxisX.IntervalType` to suitable values for your range of values.

Now you can set the `DataPoints` using the (good) `AddXY` overload and get real X-Values.  If you add them as strings the X-Values will actually be all zero, which may or may not be a problem..

Note that if you want the labels to display strictly with the `DataPoints` (instead of points on a regular grid) will may have to use `CustomLabels`..